# Room types for Reverb2 effect AU on iOS 5

Tags: ios

I'm getting a -10879 (kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty) when I try to set the ReverbRoomType property on a Reverb2 unit in iOS.Here's how I create it:

```
AudioComponentDescription outputcd = {0};
outputcd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
outputcd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2;
outputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
AUNode reverbNode;
CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(self.auGraph, &outputcd, &reverbNode), 
           "AUGraphNode[kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2] failed");
CheckError(AUGraphNodeInfo(_auGraph, reverbNode, NULL, &_auReverb),
           "AUGraphNodeInfo failed [reverbNode]");
```

And here's setting the room type (which fails the "CheckError()" call, which tests the return against noErr and logs the error before exiting). This is the call that fails with kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty:

```
 UInt32 roomType = kReverbRoomType_LargeHall;
 CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_auReverb, kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbRoomType, 
            kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &roomType, sizeof(UInt32)),
"AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbRoomType] failed");
```

I've only tried 2 different values for the property, but the error makes me think that the property constant itself is wrong.  Is this not settable on iOS 5?  Changing from kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbRoomType to kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbPreset doesn't help either.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbRoomType and kAudioUnitProperty_ReverbPreset properties apply to the 3D Mixer AU, not the Reverb2 AU.